# ASIHTTPRequest progress delegate for file upload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I use `ASIHTTPRequest` to control my progress indicator.  Also, I use the `ASIHTTPRequest` `requestFinished` delegate method to tell my controller when the request is done.  Sometimes the progress indicator indicates upload is finished a lot earlier than when the calling of `requestFinished` occurs.  Shouldn't the progress indicator finish the same time as request finished?  Or is it more standard just to use the progress indicator to indicate the number of bits uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's go back to situation. Assume your app made two requests. Then requestFinished callback will be invoked two time. But if you write something like below. The indicator will be dismissed for the first time as it expected for first request, while second request will be still in waiting for response.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   [self dismissIndicator];
}
```

So if you need to dismiss indicator when all requests will be finished, you should count them. Or if the dismissing logic is connected to the concrete url you need to check it and for example dismiss indicator. Correct me if you have another requests queue or another logic.